# How do I run a unit test with different rosparams?

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to run a ROS unittest on a Python node multiple times using different rosparam parameters?

I know how to set rosparams within the test nodes, but I don't know how to force the node under test to re-read the parameters.

Thanks,

-Jon Stephan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46365/how-do-i-run-a-unit-test-with-different-rosparams?/) by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 837 on 2012-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rostest](http://ros.org/wiki/rostest) is probably the easiest soltution.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2012-10-27**:
Sure, I'm using rostest.   But I want to run two tests with the rosparams set to two different values.  Most nodes (or at least my nodes) only read parameters on initialization.  Is there a way to tell a node to re-initialize?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-14**:
Rerun it.  There's no internal state or official starting state you can force it to return to.  If the node writers wish they can make it reread the parameters regularly, but usually it's expected to restart things.